# Synchronize panes in byobu

Tags: byobu, tmux

anything similar to

> tmux synchronize-panes on

in byobu with tmux as back-end??

I am a cluster admin and would love to use byobu rather than clusterssh which lets me do synchronous writes

Answer (score 4):

You can also easily send a command to all splits, using <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd>.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: I assume that this feature was not ready then, but now <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> toggles the send-to-all-splits mode, which is veeeeery nice for clusterssh-like behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Press the escape sequence (usually <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) and type:

```
:setw synchronize-panes on
```

to turn it *on*. To turn it off:

```
:setw synchronize-panes off
```

This works only in splits.

Comment: standard escape sequence is `alt-a`

Answer (score 1):

To simulate clusterssh behavior, you need a recent byobu version (>5.87) and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> toggle.